# Reading multiple xml files java

Tags: java, xml, merge

i have ~25000 XML files i need to read in java. This is my code:

```
private static void ProcessFile() {
    try {


        File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/Emolk/Desktop/000010.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("sindex");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("");

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Count : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("count").item(0).getTextContent());

                Entity CE = new Entity(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent(), Integer.parseInt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("count").item(0).getTextContent()));
                Entities.add(CE);
                System.out.println("Entity added! ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Entities);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

How do i read 25000 files instead of just the one?

I tried joining all the xml files together using this: https://www.sobolsoft.com/howtouse/combine-xml-files.htm

But that gave me this error:

```
[Fatal Error] joined.xml:130:2: The markup in the document following the 
root element must be well-formed.
```

Comment: Show a sample of those 25k xml files and explain what you are trying to do.Why you want to read all those at once???

Comment: Same way you do anything 25000 times: **a loop**.

Comment: @KishanCS One XML file: https://ufile.io/dny1h I need to process all 25k at once to extract the contents into Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is not a concern, then you can do something like,

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    public class ReadFiles {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            File dir = new File("D:/Work"); //Directory where your file exists

            File [] files = dir.listFiles();

            for(File file : files) {
                if(file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xml")) { //You can validate file name with extension if needed
                    ProcessFile(file, Entities);  // Assumed you have declared Entities, may be list of other collection
                }
            }

            System.out.println(Entities);
        }

        private static void ProcessFile(File fXmlFile, List<E> Entities) {
            try {

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("sindex");

                System.out.println("----------------------------");

                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                    System.out.println("");

                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                        System.out.println("Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println("Count : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("count").item(0).getTextContent());

                        Entity CE = new Entity(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent(), Integer.parseInt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("count").item(0).getTextContent()));
                        Entities.add(CE);
                        System.out.println("Entity added! ");
                    }
                }           
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it when i get home.

Answer (score 0):

To read mutliple files you should use a loop of some kind for iteration. You can either scan for all valid files in a directory.

```
File folder = new File("path/to/directory");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // you can also filter for .xml if needed
    if (files[i].isFile()) {
        // parse the file
    }
}
```

Next, you need to decide how you want to parse your files: *sequential* or *in parallel*. 
Parallel is a lot faster since you use multiple threads to parse files.

#### One Thread

You can reuse your code that you already wrote, and loop over the files:

```
for (File file : files) {
    processFile(file, yourListOfEntities);
}
```

#### Multiple Threads:

Aquire a `ScheduledExecutorService` and submit multiple tasks.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for (File file : files) {
    service.execute(() -> processFile(file, yourListOfEntities));
}
```

An important note here: The default implementation of `ArrayList` is not thread safe, so you should (since the `List` is used by multiple threads) synchronize access to it:

```
List<Entity> synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(yourListOfEntities);
```

Also, `DocumentBuilder` is not thread safe and should be created once per thread (you have it right if you just call your method). This note is just for the case if you think about optimizing it.